# Date Formatter unexpected output

Tags: swift, date, nsdateformatter, dateformatter

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMMM dd, yyyy 'at' HH:mm:ss aa z"
dateFormatter.amSymbol = "AM"
let dateString = "February 02, 2022 at 10:49:06 AM GMT+3"
print(dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)!)
```

Prints -> `2022-02-01 21:49:06 +0000`

why this prints `21:49` instead of `10:49`?

Comment: So, you'll be happy(?) to know that here, in Australia, it prints `8:49 AM`, so, it's a timezone issue :D.  Also, remember, that the `description` been printed by the `Date` is making use of the locale/timezone of the device!

Comment: i am already at gmt+3 so it should have printed 10:49? am I missing something?

Comment: So, if I do something like `dateFormatter.string(from: dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)!)` it prints `February 02, 2022 at 08:49:06 AM GMT+11`

Comment: @SelçukYıldız If you directly print a `Date` object, it always prints in UTC.

Answer (score 1):

So, yes, we're both missing something.  The time format should be use `hh` not `HH` (`HH` is for 24 hour time and some weird conversation was going in there)

So, I tested in a Playground with...

```
let threeHoursFromGMT = Measurement(value: 3, unit: UnitDuration.hours).converted(to: UnitDuration.seconds).value
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMMM dd, yyyy 'at' hh:mm:ss aa z"
dateFormatter.amSymbol = "AM"
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.init(secondsFromGMT: Int(threeHoursFromGMT))
let dateString = "February 02, 2022 at 10:49:06 AM GMT+3"
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)!
dateFormatter.string(from: dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)!)
```

And it generated

```
"Feb 2, 2022 at 6:49 PM" // let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)!
"February 02, 2022 at 10:49:06 AM GMT+3" // dateFormatter.string(from: dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)!)
```

The first output is based on my timezone (+11) and the second is based on the formatter requirements (using +3)

Comment: Thank you man :) I was trying for hours, saved my day